# How can you say that $dx * dy = 0$, or $dx^2 = 0$?

Tags: calculus

Always, when two or more infinitesimals are multiplied by each other the result is considered 0. I do not understand how you can do this. Yes, dx * dy is very small, but why can you just say it is 0? dx is already very small, in fact infinitesimal, yet you do not say it is 0.

How are you allowed to draw the line here and say that $dx^2$ is 0.

Comment: I wouldn't say it *equals* zero, but the idea is that $dx^2$ is infinitesimally small, even compared to another infinitesimal quantity. It's the same idea as $\lim_{x \to 0} \frac{x^2}{x}=0$. Both numerator and denominator are going to $0$, but the numerator is so much smaller than the denominator that it "wins." $x^2$ is much much smaller than $x$ when both of them are close to $0$.

Comment: @kccu But in a regular scenario where you have dx and regular variables, you do not simply get rid of all the dx's, right?

Comment: This is why infinitesimals fall into "non-standard analysis."  If you go that way, infinitesimals live in the spaces between real numbers, and the algebra can be defined that the product of two infinitesimals is exactly 0.  In traditional analysis these spaces do not exist.

Comment: @kccu my assumption is that since $dx \wedge dy$ is an area form, then for a sufficiently small rectangle you have $dx \wedge dy = \epsilon$. Similarly, $dx$ determines length on $\mathbb{R}$ and so if $p$ is close the origin then $dx = \epsilon$ and so $(dx^2)= \epsilon^2$. Of course they can't say things like this in a first year's calculus text, but maybe this is the reason.

Comment: @Goldname It would help if you gave an example of where you are seeing these sorts of things (saying $dx^2=0$, etc.).

Comment: Note that we have to define $dx \wedge dx = 0$ to get properties we want differential forms to have, such as $dx \wedge dy = -dy \wedge dx$

Comment: @kccu I thought this was generally true. Specifically I've seen this in one of my classes in the derivation for getting the transfer function of the lumped model transmission line

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen What is the meaning of $\wedge$?

Comment: @DougM I don't know any analysis, but I don't see how something falling into different categories of analysis have anything to do with why you can do this and it works.

Comment: @Goldname It's the Wedge Product, which you can think of as somewhat generalizing the concept of the Cross Product. It's from a branch of mathematics known as Exterior Algebra

Comment: @Goldname Note that $dV = dx_1 \wedge dx_2 \wedge\cdots\wedge dx_n$ for $n$th dimensional [volume element](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/VolumeElement.html)

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Thanks, but why do you use wedge product and not simple multiplication?

Comment: @Goldname because mathematics is about structure, and we find nice structure by defining a wedge product in a certain way. You are more than welcome to define it with standard multiplication, but you must DEFINE what $dx \cdot dx$ is, which will depend on how you define multiplication and, more importantly, how you define $dx$. You also have to decide in what contexts $dx \cdot dx = dx^2$ makes sense, which depends again on how you defined multiplication and now how you define exponentiation

Comment: If you read a real analysis textbook such as Calculus by Spivak, you will find that they avoid mentioning "infinitesimals" like $dx$ or $dy$ entirely, and simply use arguments involving limits to prove everything.  This is a very clear and very standard way of understanding calculus.  It is true that in more advanced math subjects like differential geometry or nonstandard analysis quantities like $dx$ are given a precise definition, but this is not something you need to worry about in order to understand calculus deeply.

Comment: @DougM: I'm not sure if I misunderstood the point you're trying to make, but in nonstandard analysis, no infinitesimal satisfies $x^2 = 0$. (except, of course, $x=0$).

Answer (score 2):

I'll try to answer your question with an example.

Say $f(x)=x^2$ and we want to show $\frac{df}{dx}=2x$. We compute

$${f(x+ \Delta x)-f(x)}=(x+\Delta x)^2-x^2=x^2+2x\Delta x + (\Delta x)^2-x^2= 2x\Delta x+(\Delta x)^2$$

Now we want to drop the $(\Delta x)^2$ and say that $df = 2x\ dx$, i.e., $\frac{df}{dx}=2x$. If we re-arrange the equation above, we see

$$\frac{f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)}{\Delta x}= 2x+ \Delta x$$

so as $\Delta x$ gets small, the quotient approaches just $2x$. This is because $(\Delta x)^2$ approaches zero much faster than $\Delta x$ does.

You can also see this numerically. Let's pick $x=10$ and $\Delta x = 0.01$. Then

$$f(x+\Delta x)-f(x) = 2x \Delta x + (\Delta x)^2 = 2\cdot 10 \cdot 0.01 + 0.01^2 = 0.2 + 0.0001.$$

If $\Delta x = 0.0001$, then

$$f(x+\Delta x)-f(x) = 2x \Delta x + (\Delta x)^2 = 2\cdot 10 \cdot 0.0001 + 0.0001^2 = 0.002 + 0.00000001.$$

The smaller $\Delta x$ gets, the more negligible $(\Delta x)^2$ becomes, *even compared to $\Delta x$ itself*, which is quite small.

Comment: But you can't say that $2x \Delta x = 0$ as well?

Comment: No. The idea of a differential is we want to know how $f$ changes if we change $x$. The equation $f(x+\Delta x)-f(x)= 2x \Delta x + (\Delta x)^2$ gives us this information. In particular, it tells us if $\Delta x$ is really tiny, then if we change $x$ by that tiny amount, we expect $f$ to change by  $2x$ times that amount. We cannot disregard $2x \Delta x$ because we want to know how small the change in $f$ is *relative to the change in $x$* (i.e., relative to $\Delta x$).

Answer (score 1):

I see your problem.  You are being taught calculus by a teacher (book) that cares more about intuition than rigor.  Infinitesimals are intuitive, but they lie on theoretically unstable territory, and you are sensing this instability.

The short answer is that infinitesimals are not real numbers.  And when it is time to get formal, most calculus texts do away with the concept of infinitesimals and make limits to all the heavy lifting.  This is the subject of "Real Analysis."  Which is usually not taught until after you have some mastery of calculus.

However there is a field of "Non-Standard analysis."  Non-Standard analysis brings back the infinitesimal.  And they live "between" the real numbers, and the algebra of infinitesimals is not exactly the algebra of real numbers.